# Infinite rendering of component when fetching data in useEffect wrapped in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**What I am trying to do:**

1. fetch data in useEffect from my component
2. update loading state from the HOC
3. return wrapped component /display data

**App.js**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import withFetch from "./withFetch";

const App = ({ setLoading }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    async function fetchData() {
      await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withFetch(App);
```

**withFetch /HOC:**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const withFetch = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const WithFetch = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    if (isLoading) return <h1>Loading..</h1>;

    return <WrappedComponent setLoading={setLoading} {...props} />;
  };

  return WithFetch;
};

export default withFetch;
```

**What goes wrong:**

- infinite loop from/to HOC and my component

I made a very simple demo in CodeSandbox to demonstrate my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-cache-bb044?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hooks were created to remove need for HOCs

Comment: What is your source for that statement?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#its-hard-to-reuse-stateful-logic-between-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom hook can eliminate the need for an HOC entirely, if you'd prefer that.

```
function useFetch(url) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState({
    data: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      setResult({
        isLoading: true,
        data: null,
        error: null,
      });

      try {
        const res = await axios.get(props.url);
        setResult({
          data: res.data,
          isLoading: false,
          error: null,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setResult({
          data: null,
          isLoading: false,
          error,
        });
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return result;
}

const Display = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
  );

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading..</h1>;
  } else if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else {
    return <Display data={data} />;
  }
};
```

Comment: That is smart, yes. But I wonder how I can make this custom hook work with one or more dependencies e.g. when the URL search param changes I want it to trigger the useEffect again. Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: Another thing i wonder is that - how you will combine this custom hook with a  presentations component? E.g. I want to use this custom hook in many components so I dont re-write the same fetching logic over and over again but i also dont want to write the same if-else statement to display either loading, error or data. What is my options?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as App calls `setLoading(true)`, WithFetch no longer renders WrappedComponent, so App is unmounted.

Then eventually the request succeeds, and calls `setLoading(false)`, which renders a *new* App, which invokes another request.

Instead, I think you want to co-locate the fetching code with the isLoading state.

```
// withFetch.jsx
// The withFetch HOC knows how to conditionally display a component
// depending on whether data has been fetch, and actually fetches.
// But, it doesn't know _where_ the data came from (because presumably
// you will want to reuse this for different data sets)

const withFetch = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const WithFetch = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);

      async function fetchData() {
        await axios.get(props.url).then((res) => {
          setData(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        });
      }

      fetchData();
    }, [props.url]);

    if (isLoading) {
      return <h1>Loading..</h1>;
    } else {
      return <WrappedComponent data={data} {...props} />;
    }
  };

  return WithFetch;
};


// Display.jsx
// The Display component knows how to display data after it has
// been fetched, but knows nothing about how to fetch the data
// or where it comes from.

const Display = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withFetch(Display);


// App.jsx
// The App component renders the Display component and
// provides the URL where data comes from

const App = () => {
  return <Display url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" />;
};

// do not wrap App with withFetch
```

Comment: Using your `withFetch` component in CodeSandbox throws: `Error
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`